# Django - static files gets 404 error

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

I know that there is a lot of topics about this topic, but it doesn't help me in my case. I'm really confused. My app do not see my static files.

Structure of my app:

```
myapp-
  setting-
       settings.py
       url.py
  app
       templates
       static
```

**Settings.py**

```
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), ".."))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
       "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder",
       "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder"
]
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns += patterns('', (
    r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$',
    'django.views.static.serve',
    {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}
))
```

**templates**

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<link href="{% static 'bower_components/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```

What I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'app/static'),)
```

I dont now, what is full path to your css, but you dont need full, if it is in `static` directory, just
`{% static 'your_file.css' %}`

Comment: Doesn't `django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder` search inside all apps?

Comment: nice, so you need it anyway, glad for you :)

Comment: I had the same problem, what worked for me was, adding a forward slash at the end, i.e. os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static/')